# Alert Dialog Not Showing On MainActivty Start

Tags: android, eclipse, button, dialog

When I run my application the dialog box doesnt pop up, am I missing something?

Here is my code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("This is a test!")
   .setCancelable(false)
   .setPositiveButton("I Agree", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            MainScreen.this.finish();
       }
   })
   .setNegativeButton("I Disagree", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
       }
   })
   //Set your icon here
   .setTitle("Alert!")
   .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should call `alert.show()` at the end of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found what is was I have to put alert.show(); at the end of my code.